# I try to get all data included in [] (not specific tokens!)

Tags: batch-file

I try to get all data included in [] (not specific tokens!)
I try with loop but its give only 1 parameter.

Example what I need:

```
set "x=Stackoverflow [I need it] and [I need this too] and [this too]"

output => I need it, I need this too, this too
```

Tried to do:

```
  for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ("%x%") do (
      echo %%a
  )
```

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: So what happened, and how was it contrary to your expectations? Enter `For /?` at the Command Prompt, read the usage information, paying particular attention to the `tokens` as well as `delims` .

Comment: the code looping only 1 time, like code running and giving 1 echo of x variable: output => Stackoverflow

Comment: As I told you, read the usage for the command you're using.

Comment: I tried tokens but I cant use it because I don’t know where [] will be, I gave this string for example

Comment: I asked you to show what you'd tried, you didn't show any attempts using `Tokens`. Now I'm certainly not telling you that `Tokens` are your ultimate solution, but we aren't here to spend all day trying to guess, or question you for, information you haven't told us about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "x=Stackoverflow [I need it] and [I need this too] and [this too]"

set "output=" & set "p=%x:]=" & set "output=!output!, !p:*[=!" & set "p=%"

echo output =^> %output:~2%
```

Output:

```
output => I need it, I need this too, this too
```

For an explanation of the method used, you should remove the `@echo off` line, run the program and carefully review the executed code. If you want further explanations, then review [this topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Answer (score 1):

you could use `"tokens=2,4,6,8,10,12 delims=[]"`, but it is difficult to post-process the result (removing additional commas/spaces).
The same effect can be reached by preprocessing the string and splitting with a plain `for` loop. The `flag` variable takes care of using each second token only. I added a `_` in front of the string to correctly process strings that start with a `[`. `set /a "flag=(flag+1) %% 2"` alternates the `flag` variable between `0` and `1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "x=[this] not [that] not [yes] no [in] out"
set "y=_%x:[=","%"
set "y=%y:]=","%"

set flag=0
for %%a in ("%y%") do (
  if !flag!==1 set "result=!result!, %%~a"
  set /a "flag^=1"
)
if defined result set "result=%result:~2%"
echo output = %result%
```

Output:

```
output = this, that, yes, in
```

Comment: `set /a "flag=(flag+1) %% 2"` can be simplified to `set /a "flag^=1"`. And maybe `set result=!result!, "%%~a"` so later on each extracted token can be accessed separately by another naked `FOR` though not sure if that is what the OP wanted. +1

Comment: I give u upvote but I said I dont know where placed [] in string and not a fact that the [] exists any 2 tokens, I used other way

Comment: @dauzduzTV, Did you test the code at all? It doesn't matter where in the string, `[]` appear, and the nice thing about this approach is that it doesn't matter how many of `[]` you have in the string be it 1 or 100 it extracts them all. If there is a chance for `[]` to not  present in the string then it can easily resolved by `if "%x%"=="%x:[=%"`.  And what was the other way you used?

Comment: added a line to care for "no `[]"` and implemented @sst's "flag" method (never used `OR` before with `set /a`, but yes - very useful)